# Use Bootstrap for Analytics ReportChart

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-charting

Can bootstrap be used to control the size of an Analyltics  report chart?
I have a VF page referencing the Bootstrap CSS file but the chart dis not appear to be responding to the added reference.  Am I referencing the static resource incorrectly?

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" docType="html-5.0">

<head>
<link 
href="https://c.csXX.visual.force.com/resource/1509719614000/BootStrapCSS"/>
</head> 

<apex:form >       
    <analytics:reportChart showRefreshButton="true"  cacheResults="false" reportId="00000000000000"
    filter="{column:'ACCOUNT_ID',operator:'equals',value:'{!Account.Id}'}">
</analytics:reportChart>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: you know you can check that using your browsers dev tools right? [Analyze requests](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/#analyze) Additionally, there is documentation on [Referencing a Static Resource in Visualforce Markup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources_reference.htm)

Comment: I looked at the page you referenced and that is why I was concerned that I was referencing it incorrectly since previously I could not get the syntax correct when trying to save the VF page.  I am not familiar with the browser dev tool, I will look it up. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I referencing the static resource incorrectly?

First of all, to check if your static resource is referenced properly (or even loading) you can use your browsers developer tools as mentioned in [Analyze requests](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/#analyze).  Additionally, there is documentation on [Referencing a Static Resource in Visualforce Markup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources_reference.htm)

> Can bootstrap be used to control the size of an Analyltics report
>   chart?

you can check in your browser what the `<apex:form >` and `<analytics:reportChart>` components render, and using Javascript you can add classes that bootstrap supports to apply the styling you want.
Not sure what you mean by size though, if you mean height and width, this is not specific to bootstrap, you can still change these values using javascript when your components render.

Comment: The analytics:reportChart component has an option where you can set the size of the chart ; size="small" .  I want to make sure the chart is sized correctly on the desktop and mobile.  So I was not sure if I should set the size in the  analytics:reportChart component.

Comment: yes, you can use the size attribute of the analytics:reportChart component.  however, this is not related to bootstrap

Comment: I got the bootstrap loaded as a resource and referenced on the VF page but was probably a lost cause.  It appears that the <analytics:reportChart> is unsupported in VF: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_components_unsupported.htm

Comment: unsuported in a VF app

Comment: Ok.  I just read "shouldn't be used in a VF page".  Then I am just dont have the syntax correct for the chart.  Its not a media object or image so I will try using the  Bootstrap Grid. Thx

Comment: good luck with your chart!